# Sepolia Unauthorized URL

Tags: ether, python, brownie, sepolia

Good day, Ive constantly been getting errors while working with Sepolia Test Eth with Brownie, I've checked for errors in my .envfile as well as in my brownie-config and still havent seen a ny issues, is there a solution to this

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

CrowdfundingProject is the active project.

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 13, in main
    deploy_crowdfunding()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 8, in deploy_crowdfunding
    crowd_fund = CrowdFunding.deploy({"from": account})
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 510, in deploy
    receipt, exc = self._make_transaction(
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 720, in _make_transaction
    gas_price, gas_strategy, gas_iter = self._gas_price(gas_price)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 456, in _gas_price
    return web3.eth.generate_gas_price(), None, None
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 986, in generate_gas_price
    return self._generate_gas_price(transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 214, in _generate_gas_price
    return self.gasPriceStrategy(self.web3, transaction_params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\gas_strategies\rpc.py", line 20, in rpc_gas_price_strategy      
    return web3.manager.request_blocking(RPC.eth_gasPrice, [])
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 197, in request_blocking
    response = self._make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 150, in _make_request
    return request_func(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\gas_price_strategy.py", line 90, in middleware       
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\attrdict.py", line 33, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\formatting.py", line 94, in middleware
    response = make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\buffered_gas_estimate.py", line 40, in middleware    
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\middleware\exception_retry_request.py", line 105, in middleware 
    return make_request(method, params)
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\providers\rpc.py", line 88, in make_request
    raw_response = make_post_request(
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\web3\_utils\request.py", line 113, in make_post_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\Tolu\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/
```

My Infura API Key is correct and this is what I used to add Sepolia to my brownie networks list

```
brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host=https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID chainid=11155111 multicall2='0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696' explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api name="Sepolia (Infura)"
```

I've tried multiple solutions and still none works, my .env file has no spaces near it everything is supposed to be working fine

Comment: if you are using an infura API key, make sure it is correct.

Comment: My infura API key is correct still no change